# Best way to handle more complex validation logic (required fields, etc.) on Backbone Model/View?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette, backbone-events

While Backbone's built-in `validate()` method on Models works fairly well for very simplistic cases, it quickly begins to fall apart when working on more complex validation logic, such as required fields. On the Model, here's how I'd typically handle validation of an attribute:

```
validate: function (attrs) {
    var invalid = [],
        dateRegex = /^(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4})$/,
        timeRegex = /^(\d{2}):(\d{2})$/,
        isoDateTimeRegex = /^(\d{4})-(\d{1,2})-(\d{1,2})T(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})$/;

    if (_.has(attrs, "chosenScheduleDate") && !dateRegex.test(attrs.chosenScheduleDate)) {
        invalid.push("chosenScheduleDate");
    }

    // ...some more validation rules

    if (invalid.length > 0) {
        return invalid;
    }
},
```

And then, within the View, filter through invalid attributes using the new-ish `invalid` event:

```
modelEvents: {
    "invalid": "invalidateAttributes"
},

// ...other code

invalidateAttributes: function (model, error) {
    if (_.contains(error, "chosenScheduleDate")) {
        this.unsetModelAttributes("chosenScheduleDate", "chosenScheduleOpenTime", "scheduleOpenTime");

        this.statusNotification.show.call(this, localizedText.displayText.theSelectedDateIsInvalid, "error");

        this.ui.chosenScheduleDateInput.addClass("text-input--error");
    }
},
```

This can result in an invalidateAttributes method that's quite long, especially if I'm validating 6+ Model attributes. Additionally, this doesn't take into consideration the concept of required fields, which I've handled by doing disagreeable `has()` checks:

```
if (this.model.has("scheduleOpenTime")) {
    $.when(this.parent.saveAppointment.call(this))
        .done(function () {
            // set a new attribute on the model that represents the successfully-persisted datetime value
            that.model.set("savedScheduleOpenTime", that.model.get("scheduleOpenTime"));

            that.renderAppointmentForm();
        });
}
```

And then would have to `unset()` attributes when they're invalid during an attempted set, effectively only allowing valid attributes to exist at all on the Model at any given time.

Is there a better, more elegant way to handle more complex validation, including required fields, on Backbone Models? Would really prefer a simplistic approach that doesn't utilize a heavyweight solution like the Backbone.Validation plugin or whatnot. Would love to see what kinds of patterns others are using.

Answer (score 1):

Addy Osmani's Backbone Fundamentals book has **[a great section](http://addyosmani.github.io/backbone-fundamentals/#better-model-property-validation)** about model property validation. Using the **[Backbone.Validation plugin](https://github.com/thedersen/backbone.validation)** would have been my first suggestion since it handles required fields pretty nicely, but you explicitly mentioned wanting to avoid that. Addy's discussion of the topic touches on some alternatives including the **[Backbone.validateAll](http://gregfranko.com/blog/backbone-dot-validateall-plugin/)** plugin, or focusing on validating forms instead of models.